# How to extract date from date time in php

Tags: php, datetime

i have a field in my model called creation_time whose type is datetime.
so `echo $model->creation_date;die();` will display a value like this

```
2015-10-07 09:55:17
```

i want to get only the date ie, 2015-10-07.How can i do that?
i have tried something like this

```
$d = date('Y-m-d', $model->creation_date);
echo $d ; die();
```

but i got an error which says `A non well formed numeric value encountered`

then i tried like this

```
$s = $model->creation_date;
$dt = new DateTime($s);
$date = $dt->format('m/d/Y');echo $date; die();
```

now i get error like this `'app\controllers\DateTime' not found`

Comment: use date('Y-m-d', strtotime($model->creation_date));

Comment: Please try add "\" before datetime like \DateTime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like below and let me know.

```
$d = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($model->creation_date));
echo $d; die();
```

Comment: its working. but when i tried DateTime with '\' my solution too worked.

Comment: @AjithN Yes its working too. :)